# Numerically stable simplification of sinc function

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

I would like to know if there is an alternate, explicit (non-iterative) form of the `sinc` function which behaves in a numerically stable way for all real numbers. The definition I am aware of is:

$$\texttt{sinc}(a) = \dfrac{\sin(a)}{a}$$

However, although this function is well-defined everywhere [(even at 0)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(a%2F2)%2Fa), this function presents problems when implemented in code and evaluated at 0. I would like to know if there is an alternate form involving simple functions which would avoid possible division by 0 when we try to implement this is code.

Some programming packages (like numpy in python) provide a `sinc` function, presumably to sidestep this issue. But I would like to know generally if there is a better way of implementing it in an arbitrary language without resorting to some `if` statement. For instance, `numpy` simply checks if `a=0`. If it is, then it replaces `a` with some small value $\neq 0$. Specifically:

```
def sinc(x):
    y = pi * where(x == 0, 1.0e-20, x)
    return sin(y)/y
```

---

### EDIT

As Sangchul Lee points out, you could consider the series form, but that representation will break down for large $a$. So the series form is essentially pushing the problem somewhere else (from a numerical point of view). Furthermore, you might consider switching between the two forms depending on whether $a$ is small, but that is introducing its own `if` statement, and I would like to avoid a piecewise solution.

Note: I have no idea what tags to use here. So please update the tags to what you view as appropriate.

Comment: Is it an option for you to utilize the following series expansion?$$\operatorname{sinc}(a) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} a^{2n} $$ This formula works especially nice when $a$ is near zero.

Comment: This will not work nice numerically. This pushes the problem somewhere else. Specifically, while your formula will work nice around 0, it will break for large $a$. So it isn't really a general form that is numerically stable

Comment: As far as I know, many special functions are implemented in piecewise manner in order to achieve numerical stability for a wide range of parameters, so I guess it is of no harm to adopt the same strategy here. For instance, you can use the above formula when $a$ is within certain threshold and then use $\sin(a)/a$ otherwise.

Comment: The problem is when it comes to differentiation. I would like to use this in an autodifferentiation package, and if I have a piecewise form, then I have to insert a lot of nasty switches, particularly with higher derivatives.

Comment: If I have to do it, then so be it. But if there is a nice, numerically stable, continuous representation that I can use, I would strongly prefer that.

Comment: I see, that might be a huge problem. To be honest, it seems the best if the package allows you to designate higher-derivatives of $\operatorname{sinc}$ as well, so that you can provide your own implementations of higher derivatives. Or, if it is guaranteed that the argument will be bounded within certain range, I guess that the following formula $$ \operatorname{sinc}(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right) $$ might be also useful.

Comment: If you are concerned about symbolic derivatives, you can use the hypergeometric representation $\sin(z)/z = {}_{0}F_{1}(\tfrac{3}{2}, -\tfrac{1}{4}z^2)$

Comment: May be another option is to use the spherical Bessel function if available: $\mathrm{sinc}(x)=j_0(x)$

Comment: @SangchulLee is correct, branching is the right way to have fast and stable evaluation for a wide variety of parameters. If branching breaks auto differentiation, that's a problem with the auto diff package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a must, you may consider (with or without $\pi$)
$$
\text{sinc}(x)\approx\frac{\sin\left(\pi\left|x\right|+\epsilon\right)}{\pi\left|x\right|+\epsilon},
$$
where $\epsilon>0$ is a small parameter, preferably your machine epsilon.

Comment: That is a pretty good idea. I don't like the fact that it is an approximation. But a good idea nonetheless

Comment: @bremen_matt: Sure, I understand your point. Getting rid of "if" could make your scheme more efficient, especially if you need to call $\text{sinc}$ for times. Approximation is another alternative; imperfect, though. It really depends on your demand. Like my MATLAB platform, $\sin\pi$ is not exactly $0$, but some $10^{-16}$ instead (agree with my machine epsilon), even if $\sin x$ is without any approximation. Maybe you could relax your target a bit, because there are round-off errors anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For small $x$ the following definition is very well-behaved numerically:

$$\mathrm{sinc}(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(1+\frac{x}{\pi})\Gamma(1-\frac{x}{\pi})}$$

Comment: Why do you think this is well-behaved numerically?

Comment: @user14717 Because $\Gamma$ is well-behaved around $1$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+Gamma(x)+from+0.5+to+1.5 There are no $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$ numerical issues.

Comment: The $1+x/\pi$ indicates it is limited in precision by the unit roundoff, which is large for floating point numbers.